# Compiler compiler for ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, antlr, yacc, compiler-compiler

I have some files that I've written in a custom scripting language which I would like to be able to read and execute in ActionScript.  Does AS have a compiler generator along the lines of lex/yacc or ANTLR?

Answer (score 0):

One of the first results for a search on "actionscript parser generator" will show [ASYACC](http://code.google.com/p/sepy-asyaac/) that is a port of YACC for ActionScript.

It is not the only result, btw.